# How to accommodate minutely and hourly data in the same visualisation?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

**Current Scenario -**

The current dashboard is set to Sum aggregation at minutely level. My dashboard currently works only when interval is set to minutely. If I change the interval the current graph shows incorrect values. This happens due to the fact that there are **more than 1 documents generated per minute** and the correct value per minute will be the **sum of the field values at minutely level**. 
So even today we are obliged to use minute interval but I'm fine with this.

Now the hourly documents is designed to ingest data after doing all the math( and we have validated the ingestion logic). So there is 1 doc per hour.  This is the reason the visualisation is not able to accommodate both types of data. 
If I had a scenario like **1 document per minute** and then **1 document per hour**, then I could have gone with using average metrics or perhaps max metrics but at present the problem is I have to do sum of the doc values for a minute (mandatory), therefore, whatever internal logic applies for minutely data gets also applied to hourly too.

Is there a way where I can show both types of data in the same graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, the approach is wrong.
Having n documents per minute (where n depends on the no. of hosts in that cluster) and then 1 document per hour per type is illogical from visualisation perspective because the actual value needed was the sum of all n documents generated per min and so the sum metric that was being applied at minutely level was also getting applied at hourly data. If we wanted to accommodate both types of data in the same graph, there is a need of uniformity and thus, aggregate the data at minutely level from other end and then send aggregated data to elastic.